# How to return values from an ajax call along with HTML result?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I've my jquery code as

```
 $(function() {
    $("#addline").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "proc/add-line.php",
            data: // some string,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("ul#nextLines").append(html);

                if(lineId == 10) {                // lineId value to be passed from add-line.php
                    $("#addForm").hide();
                }
            }
        });
        }return false;
    }); 
});
```

In the line commented as "// lineId to be passed from add-line.php" [refer to code above], I want the php processing page add-line.php to pass the value of the var lineId.

At present, the add-line.php gives out a html code `<li><?php echo $line; ?></li>`. Along with that, I want to send the value of the lineId so that I can implement that conditioning.

So how should I send and then retrieve the value of the lineId (retrieved in the form of a PHP variable) from add-line.php??

**Update**

I've made changes to my code above as

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "proc/add-line.php",
                data: dataString,
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data.html);
                    $("ul#nextLines").append(data.html);
                    $("ul#nextLines li:last").fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#flash").hide();

                    if(data.lineId == 10) {
                        $("#addForm").hide();
                    }
                }

            });
```

And PHP code is

```
    // Header type
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $data = array(
        "html"=> "test",
        "lineId" => "1" 
    );

    echo json_encode($data);
```

I've not been able to retrieve the json. (even the `alert(data.html)` in the success function call doesn't show up).

Can you help me figure this out?? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to return [JSON](http://json.org/) with [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
$data = array('html'=> "<li>$line</li>",
    'lineId' => $lineId //wherever that comes from
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "proc/add-line.php",
        data: // some string,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $("ul#nextLines").append(data.html);

            if(data.lineId == 10) {
                $("#addForm").hide();
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is the 'data' in "function(data)" called at success?? Does it have to do anything with the data string being passed over to the php processing page??

Comment: @ptamzz: No, it is the name I gave the parameter, you can call it whatever you want. It is the data you **get** from the PHP script and the value will be a JavaScript object with two properties, `html` and `lineId`.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:

Either return JSON from your PHP script:

```
// In PHP:
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode(array(
    'html' => '<li>' . intval($lineId) . '</li>',
    'lineId' => $lineId,
));

// In JS:
success: function(json){
    var lineId = json.lineId;
    var html = json.html;
    // ...
}
```

Due to the Content-Type header being set to application/json, jQuery will automatically parse the result as JSON. So the first parameter of the success callback is the parsed JSON object.

Or return the lineId in a HTTP header:

```
// In PHP
header('X-LineId: ' . $lineId);

// In JS
success: function(html, textStatus, xhr){
    var lineId = xhr.getResponseHeader('X-LineId');
    // ...
}
```

Comment: in the JS part (first example), I had put "alert(lineId);" after the line "var lineId = json.lineId;" but the alert pops up with an 'undefined'?? Do you know what could be the problem??

Comment: have you added the `header('Content-Type: ...)` line ? what the PHP script is returning exactly ? what alert(json) prints ?

Comment: yes I've put the `header('Content-Type: ...)` line (please refer to the updated section in my question above for the PHP code). Now I implemented your first  example. `alert(json)` doesn't print anything. Do you think it is a issue from my PHP code?? I read in another Question here at stackoverflow, someone wrote it may not work at localhost with Windows. Do you know if it is true?? (As im working on that environment only)

Comment: Given your updated question, it looks like the success callback is never executed. There must be an error with the PHP script.